# Class Object creation with python, How to specify a specific type as entry?

Tags: python, class, object

I would like to create a class in Python.
Is it possible to specify the type of argument given in **init** ? Otherwise raise an error or smth like this ?

I would like to create this type of class :
where
ligne_225 is a list
data is a dataframe

```
class Poste_HTB_HTA:
  def __init__(self, ligne_225,data):
    self.ligne_225 = ligne_225

    self.data = data


  def ligne_225(self):
    return self.ligne_225
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
class Poste_HTB_HTA:
  def __init__(self, ligne_225: list, data: pandas.dataframe):
    if not isinstance(ligne_225, list): #Checks if ligne_225 is a instance of list
        raise TypeError("ligne_225 must be of type 'list'")
    if not isinstance(data, pandas.dataframe): #Checks if data is a instance of dataframe
        raise TypeError("data must be of type 'dataframe'")
    
    self.ligne_225 = ligne_225
    self.data = data


  def ligne_225(self):
    return self.ligne_225
```

Answer (score 0):

something like the below

```
from typing import Dict


class Poste_HTB_HTA:
    def __init__(self, ligne_225: int, data: Dict) -> None:
        if not isinstance(ligne_225, int):
            raise ValueError(f'{ligne_225} must be int')
        self.ligne_225 = ligne_225
        self.data = data

    def ligne_225(self) -> int:
        return self.ligne_225
```

Comment: Note that `int` and `Dict` are just type hints and has no effect in runtime.